# How to hide y axis?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, yaxis

I plot a horizontal boxplot in MATLAB -- `boxplot(y, group,'orientation','horizontal')`, and then hide the y-axis using `set(gca,'box','off','ycolor','w')`.

It looks fine on the screen - only the bottom x-axis is visible. But whenever I save the figure to file, using either the `print()` function or `matlabfrag.m`, the left y-axis reappears in the output file (although it doesn't show up in MATLAB's visualization of the figure).

How can I keep this y-axis hidden?

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old post, but the following also remove the tick marks which is probably what you want:

```
set(gca, 'YTick', []);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
ax1 = gca;                   % gca = get current axis
ax1.YAxis.Visible = 'off';   % remove y-axis
ax1.XAxis.Visible = 'off';   % remove x-axis
```

Comment: Please give some explanation why your code is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Before exporting the figure, do

```
set(gcf, 'InvertHardCopy', 'off');
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove labels from a plot, use the following commands for X-axis or Y-axis:

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{' '})
set(gca,'YTickLabel',{' '})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me sometime ago with another property. The only way to keep the property was saving directly from the figure menu! I know that it is boring, but helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not relevant to the old versions, but here is how I did mine.

```
plot(X,Y)                    
ylabel('Intensity [a.u.]');      %creates y axis label named 'Intensity [a.u.]'
yticklabels(' ');                %sets tick labels to ' ' (space)
```

This might be what is shown in other explanations, but those made no sense to me. I am using version 2021a.